# Is there any way to still use FQL with Swift?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was wondering if there was a possible way to use FQL with Swift. I've tried to look through the graph api and wasn't able to find the functionality that I needed.

I'm basically trying to get all the user likes, posts (graph api can provide this), and comments. If there's a better way to get all the comments that a user has posted, both on their posts and other posts, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: FQL has been dead for ages already. And Graph API does not provide a way to get the information you want. There is no way to query for “all comments made by user”, at most you can go through specific posts, get all their comments, and then check if any of those were made by your user. But that is not really practicable, for anything but a small amount of posts, you will likely run into the request limits pretty soon. Plus, you would have to have access to those posts in the first place - which you won’t, unless the user whose post someone is commenting on, gave your app permission first.

Comment: That's unfortunate I guess. Thanks for letting me know, I know there's an activity log and a Time on facebook, but I was wondering if it was possible to get this through the the facebook API. I read that activity log wasn't allowed due to privacy concerns, but I was wondering if this was also the case with Time per day. Thanks!